# Из JQuery в JavaScript или Разрешение экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите плиз переписать в чистый js или подскажите как сделать так что бы этот код запускался на определенном экране.

```js
var allOptions = $("#w0").children('li:not(.init)');
$("#w0").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
  allOptions.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $("#w0").children('.init').html($(this).html());
  allOptions.toggle();
});
```

Я пробовал это сделать вот так

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 568) {
    var allOptions = $("#w0").children('li:not(.init)');
    $("#w0").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
      allOptions.removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $("#w0").children('.init').html($(this).html());
      allOptions.toggle();
    });
  }
});
```

Но JS ругается на $ и перестает работать.

Comment: а вы jquery подключили??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 568) {
      var allOptions = $("#w0").children('li:not(.init)');

      $("#w0").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
        allOptions.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $("#w0").children('.init').html($(this).html());
        allOptions.toggle();
      });
    }
  });

  // Vanilla JS

  window.onresize = () => {
      const width = window.innerWidth;
      if (width < 568) {
          const w0 = document.getElementById('#w0');

          const options = Array.from(w0.children).filter(element => !element.classList.contains('init'));
          const options2 = Array.from(w0.children).filter(element => element.classList.contains('init'));

          options.forEach(element => {
              element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                  options.forEach(x => {
                      x.classList.toggle('selected');
                  });

                  event.target.classList.add('selected');

                  options2.forEach(v => {
                      v.innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
                  });

                  options.forEach(z => {
                      const s = z.style.display;
                      z.style.display = s == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
                  });
              });
          })   
      }
  }
```

Может как то так

Comment: Не знаю в чем причина, но начало работать вот в таком формате

if ($(window).width() < 568) {
  $("#w0").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("#w0").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
  });
}